# Problem with import from Bootstrap in javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, import, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use bootstrap not only in html but also in my JavaScript/TypeScript. I imported bootstrap min js and min css in my html. In my TypeScript used this: `import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";`

When I try to use this code:

```
 var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('popup'), {
      keyboard: false
 })
 myModal.hide()
```

the chrome console said:

*Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "bootstrap". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need any imports in this case, you can use it without import.

```js
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('popup'), {
      keyboard: false
 });
 
 console.log(myModal);
```

```html
<div id="popup">popup</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I need the import else i get a Compile error https://imgur.com/a/gkSXAhG

Comment: then you have to load it via package.json but not CDN.
Add dependency in your package.json
1. remove script with CDN from HTML
2. call `npm i bootstrap` --save in your terminal (on the level of package json)
3. add import
4. restart your project

Comment: or if you have no package.json try to remove `type="module"` from script tag and `import` inside the script. In this case you don't need import anymore.

Comment: I tried all your you steps but 1. I think I need the CDN in the HTML to keep the frontend running. 2. The original error is back : Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "bootstrap". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Here is my package.json: https://imgur.com/a/XzCsdN3

Comment: 1. you have invalid package.json, it seems like your project doesn't use it at all because it doesn't have even `scripts` tag 2. it doesn't load because your file is a module, so you have to have a proper configuration or remove type="module" attribute from your script if it presented and import statement, because variable bootstrap will be available in all scripts by default

Comment: or try const bootstrap = window.bootstrap; instead of import

Comment: where is the type="module" I can't find it